# Knockout access observable dynamically based on property name

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have a viewmodel with a property as an observable.
I have a list of property names and errors being returned from server side validation. I need to access the observable based on the property name and set the errors. I want to make this generic.

ViewModel:

```
var model = ko.validatedObservable({reason: ko.observable()});
```

I need to do something like this:

```
var propName = "reason";
model[propName]("Something random");
```

Can I dynamically access the observable in this way? (doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it this way: 'model' is an observable variable loaded with an object.  That suggests we should read the observable first, and then access the object property:

```
var model = ko.validatedObservable({ reason: ko.observable() });
var propName = "reason";
model()[propName]("Something random");
```

Notice I'm reading model as an observable (model()), and then accessing the object property (model()[propName]).